# Access a method of a class defined within a method

Tags: java

It seems like PdCar class have been upcast to Car type, and I can't find a way to use methods that are not in Car interface. I'm just curious, is there a way to access readLabel method? Or it's just not possible? 
Thanks.

```
interface Car{

     }

public class Parcel5 {

    public Car car(String s){

        class PdCar implements Car {
            private String label;
            private PdCar(String whereTo){
                label = whereTo;
                  }
            public String readLabel(){ return label; }
             }
         return new PdCar(s);
          }

public static void main(String [] args){

    Parcel5 p = new Parcel5();
    Car d =  p.car("toyota");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like PdCar class have been upcast to Car type

no.

If you want to access methhod `readLabel()` you have to declare it in the interface `Car`.

> I can't find a way to use methods that are not in Car interface. I'm just curious, is there a way to access readLabel method? Or it's just not possible? Thanks.

```
interface Car{
    String readLabel()
}

public class Parcel5 {

    public Car car(String s){

        class PdCar implements Car {
            private String label;
            private PdCar(String whereTo){
                label = whereTo;
                  }
            public String readLabel(){ return label; }
             }
         return new PdCar(s);
          }

public static void main(String [] args){

    Parcel5 p = new Parcel5();
    Car d =  p.car("toyota");
    System.out.println(d.readLabel());
   }
}
```